# Instance variables reset to default after instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, visual-studio-2013

I created a class to hold some email data:

```
public class EmailClass{
    public string sender;
    public string receiver;
    public string message;

    public EmailClass(string sender, string receiver, string message){
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Message{ get; set; }    
}
```

In my web application, I have a page: `MyHome.aspx.cs` (created in the same namespace as `EmailClass`):

```
public partial class MyHome: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmailClass obj = new EmailClass("sender", "receiver", "a message");
        Response.Write("Info: " + obj.Sender + " " + obj.Receiver + " " + obj.Message);
    }
}
```

What I expected when Home.aspx is loaded is to display:

```
Info: sender receiver a message
```

However, it shows

```
Info:
```

---

It seems that the instance variables from `EmailClass` was reset to their default when I try to access them in page load. For debugging purposes, I added a MessageBox to display the instance variables values in the constructor (the constructor was invoked and the values was set during instantiation).

**My quesiton**: So what is causing the instance variables' values to be reset / not showing up?

Note: When I explicitly set the values of the object, it did show up during page load. I.e.: `obj.Sender = "sender";`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up **fields** and **auto-implemented properties**. `this.sender` is not the same as `this.Sender`. You don't need the fields when using auto-implemented properties. The fields are generated by the compiler.

This will fix it:

```
public class EmailClass
{
    public EmailClass(string sender, string receiver, string message)
    {
        this.Sender = sender;
        this.Receiver = receiver;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Message{ get; set; }    
}
```

---

If you want the implement the fields yourself, you could do this:

```
public class EmailClass
{
    private string sender;
    private string receiver;
    private string message;

    public EmailClass(string sender, string receiver, string message)
    {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public string Sender 
    { 
        get { return this.sender; } 
        set { this.sender = value; }
    }
    public string Receiver
    { 
        get { return this.receiver; } 
        set { this.receiver = value; }
    }
    public string Message
    { 
        get { return this.message; } 
        set { this.message = value; }
    }
}
```

So, it's either the first way or the second way. The second way is only useful when validating the value in the setter or raise an INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Have been spending so much time trying to figure out what happened. I came from a Java background and expect the compiler to differentiate between this.xxx and xxx. Thanks a lot. I will read up on auto-implemented properties. Will accept your answer when time lock is over.

Comment: You could start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx  Happy coding....

Comment: @user3437460 - it's nothing to do with `this.xxx` vs `xxx`, as Jeroen's second example hopefully makes clear.